# Will the bounty return to the op if the question is closed?

Tags: discussion

If a bounty question is closed will the bounty returned to the op?

This [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395896/crash-when-maximizing-thunderbird-on-13-10/421616#comment542191_395896) is what made me ask

Answer (score 10):

Moderators *can* refund bounties. We have a few powers that aren't widely advertised because they're things that need doing but we don't want every person who didn't get an answer crying foul.

A refund will usually only be given to keep things fair but it's completely up to the discretion of the moderator. **Not getting an answer after 7 days is *not* a decent enough reason in most cases (so don't bother us about it).**

Comment: I understand that mods shouldn't be bothered over this, but shouldn't the help center give a hint of this?

Comment: @Jobin then moderators would be bothered each time people doesn't get an answer for their bounty.

Answer (score 4):

The [help-center](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) clarifies it all:

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under **any** circumstances.

So, nopes, even if the question is closed, you won't get the bounty back, its just lost!

Comment: But why a moderator put a comment like that?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Moderators, I believe, have the power to increment/decrement reputation, so this one **may be** a manually returned bounty.

Comment: Sorry to say you're wrong on both counts. We can refund and we can't change arbitrarily reputation scores. Just imagine the chaos that would cause.